# All of the sudden my grease pencil image turned green

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I was working on making a character outline and suddenly the outline turns green. None of my materials are green. I noticed that there is one black line and the display is on viewport shading. Here is a picture below. If you need more info please respond.

[image]

Comment: you're seeing the onion skin, only the black line is on the current frame.try the up/down arrows to go back to the right keyframe

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Comment: Please don't add "solved" as title. Write an answer and accept it instead

Comment: Thanks to wilks, I was not in the current keyframe.